# Multiple where through relation (not chained) Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

This is a simple example of my situation:

There is a model `User` that hasOne `UserInfo`.

I want to retrieve a User via (where) different UserInfo columns, but I don't want all the wheres to be chained and specifically I don't want the `->get()` being chained at the end of where clauses.

All solutions examples and documentation I've read lead to an endless where chaining ending with a `->get()`. For some reason `whereHas` also stops working when I move the get to a next line. Maybe my syntax is wrong.

I prefer using Eloquent but if something like that can be achieved only by using the DB class I wont mind.

Expample (simplified but that's the most of it):

```
$applicant = User::whereHas('UserInfo', function($query) use ($request) {
             $query->where('gender', $request->gender);
        })->get();
```

This works perfectly. However (except of being a weird bloat of code for a single `where`, when relationship in other cases are so powerful) I want to remove the `User::` and the `->get();` from there. Meaning looking to achieve something like this:

```
$user = new User;

$user->whereHas('UserInfo', function($query) use ($request) {
     return $query->where('gender', $request->gender);
});

return $user->get();
```

And for whoever wants to read more code here's the full snippet

```
    $user = new User;
    if(! empty($request->gender))
    {
        $user->whereHas('UserInfo', function($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('gender', $request->gender);
        });
    }
    if(! empty($request->role_id))
    {
        $user->whereHas('UserInfo', function($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('role_id', $request->role_id);
        });
    }

    $applicant = $user->get();
```

Comment: *but I don't want all the wheres to be chained* why you don't need to go with this approach can you elaborate it more , Also include some code to set an example of how you wanna do it

Comment: I added some more info and some sample code. Thank you!

Comment: I guess this should do your job `$user = $user->whereHas....`

Comment: Oh, so I have to reassign it to $user again and again for each where. I think this works now. Thank you! :)

Comment: Nope you don't need to reassign for each where , you newly updated code should also work

Comment: I managed to get the last snippet I've posted to work. But it only does when I use `$user = ` on every line, otherwise it returns empty result at the end in any condition.

Comment: I guess you have solved it